# Should I use is/was in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

It has been a long chain of email with the person, who I will be meeting with, for an interview and the person emphasizes something twice in the email, so I am responding to him.

> Noted! And yes my original plan is/was to arrive early for direction and security purposes, so I do appreciate the reminder.

**Q** is it correct to use is/was here and does the sentence follow right

Answer (score 1):

Either of these would be fine and I have seen/used both of them.
Picking between them is usually based on the context. If you are responding to something they have said about related to your plan, which it seems like you are, then you would normally use "my plan was". If you were telling them your plan for the first time and not responding to any related comment from them you would pick "my plan is"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though I have not mentioned my plan explicitly because I assumed known that there is a security check I have to arrive early. SO now I am trying to reassure this plan.